# Error accessing 0x13: Check your I2C address

Tags: raspbian, hardware, sensor

When I run this (`sudo i2cdetect -y 1`):

I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- 13 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Can anyone tell me if 0x13 is the right address?

I'm getting an error when trying to interact with VCNL4000 sensor.

UPDATE:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from VCNL4000 import VCNL4000
import time

# ===========================================================================
# Example Code
# ===========================================================================

# Initialise the VNCL4000 sensor
vcnl = VCNL4000(0x13)

# Print proximity sensor data every 100 ms
while True:

    print "Data from proximity sensor", vcnl.read_proximity()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

CPU info:

```
Processor   : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS    : 697.95
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware    : BCM2708
Revision    : 000e
Serial      : 000000007b9b5e3c
```

/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf content:

```
# blacklist spi and i2c by default (many users don't need them)

#blacklist spi-bcm2708
#blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

Comment: How are you truing to interact with your sensor?

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski: Updated my question

Comment: could you please also show us your `/proc/cpuinfo` ?

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski: Sure, updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Everything is correct. Do you run your script with sudo?

Comment: @Krzysztof Adamski: yes, otherwise I'm getting an error that I don't have permissions

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski: What about the raspi-blacklist.conf file? Can you check my last update with content of raspi-blacklist.conf file ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9661/discussion-between-el-severo-and-krzysztof-adamski)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the things to check:

1. *If you can communicate with the device.* You should take a look at the [datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83798/vcnl4000.pdf) (section `REGISTER FUNCTIONS`) for the register numbers. `VCNL4000` uses `0x81` register as a `Product ID Revision` register. You can check it's content with command `sudo i2cget -y 1 0x13 0x81`. `1` is your bus number `0x13` is the device address, `0x81` is the register address. According to datasheet, this command should print `0x11`. If you get this, then the communication with the device is fine.
2. *If your script/library uses proper bus number.* For revision 2 of model B it should be `1` while for revision `1` it should be `0`. This is why I asked for `/proc/cpuinfo` content in the commends. The version of the library I found [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code) uses revision number to automatically select proper bus number but the one you can find [here](https://github.com/marcoschwartz/RaspberryPiCode) seems to be the older version without such checks (by default it uses bus number `0` so it's not the proper bus for your revision).